# Linux equivalent of fork1 of solaris

Tags: linux, fork, solaris, solaris-10, rhel6

Is there any `Linux` equivalent of `fork1` of `Solaris`? The Solaris man pages say: A  call to `fork()` is identical to a call to `fork1();` only the calling thread is replicated in the child process. This is the POSIX-specified behavior for `fork()`.

Comment: Maybe something can be emulated with the generic [`clone` Linux system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) (which is the base of both `fork` and `pthread_create` on Linux)?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the Linux `fork()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html):

> ...
>
> Note the following further points:
>
> - **The child process is created with a single thread**—the one that called `fork()`.  The entire virtual address space of the parent is
>     replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition
>     variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of `pthread_atfork(3)`
>     may be helpful for dealing with problems that this can cause.
>
> ...

Since both `fork()` and `fork1()` on Solaris replicate only the calling thread in the child process, the Linux `fork()` call would be the equivalent.